# ArtifactTransferException:

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

> Failed to execute goal on project J2EE2: Could not resolve
>   dependencies for project com.example.j2ee2:J2EE2:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:
>   The following artifacts could not be resolved: javax.jms:jms:jar:1.1,
>   com.sun.jdmk:jmxtools:jar:1.2.1, com.sun.jmx:jmxri:jar:1.2.1: Could
>   not transfer artifact javax.jms:jms:jar:1.1 from/to java.net
>   (https://maven-repository.dev.java.net/nonav/repository): No connector
>   available to access repository java.net
>   (https://maven-repository.dev.java.net/nonav/repository) of type
>   legacy using the available factories AsyncRepositoryConnectorFactory,
>   WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory

I've updated all my "lastUpdated" files, still I'm repeatedly getting the same error all the time. Is this error arising because I don't have `setting.xml` in my `.m2`?

Answer (score 0):

Either one of the options:

1 - This repository that your configuration is trying to download the dependency doesn't exists (https://maven-repository.dev.java.net/nonav/repository)

2 - You are in a machine under a proxy and it is not configured in your maven settings.xml file (whether it is on .m2 or $MAVEN_HOME/conf )

3 - See if your eclipse is usign the maven installation or the embeded maven installation (change to maven installation)

Hope it help