# Maven unable to download dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, maven-3, pom.xml

For some reason Maven is not updating the dependencies.
I tried 1) update the maven global indexes in global reopsitory
        2) The settings.xml is configured properly 
        3) mvn clean install -U (force update)
        4) Also deleted the .m2 repository

I can access http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/jms/jms/1.1/jms-1.1.pom from browser

***Error***: ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact javax.jms:jms:jar:1.1 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): null to http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/javax/jms/jms/1.1/jms-1.1.jar
Below is the pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.jms</groupId>
  <artifactId>actmq</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
        <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: You may check this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19455056/artifacttransferexception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get a 404 Error on visiting this link: http://central.maven.org/maven2/javax/jms/jms/1.1/jms-1.1.jar

It seems like the JAR is not available and only the POM is available. If you do not explicitly need the mentioned version 1.1, then you can try upgrading it to the latest version.

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
     <artifactId>javax.jms-api</artifactId>
     <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

JAR is available for this version. Link:
http://central.maven.org/maven2/javax/jms/javax.jms-api/2.0.1/javax.jms-api-2.0.1.jar